# Overriding Method Parameter Object Behavior

Tags: java

```
public void method (AmazingObject obj) {

    HashMap<Integer, AmazingObject> hashmap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        obj = new AmazingObject();
        hashmap.put(i, obj);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(hashmap.get(i).toString());
    } 

}
```

I wrote this code out and see that the array contains completely different objects for every element. If I understand this properly:

1) The method accepts a `reference copy` of an AmazingObject instance.

2) I assign a new address to that `reference type` by using the `new` keyword.

3) Another `reference copy` containing my new address is thrown into the Hashmap.

Therefore, none of the previous values are overwritten. Is the reason for this behavior that Java is pass by `reference copy` and not pass by `reference`? I would have expected every element in the array to point to the exact same object at the end (i.e. the last assigned object).

Comment: I read that question, that's where I got my information from. Im just wondering if this is the case. Is it correct to expect totally different objects across the HashMap?

Comment: you keep on reassigning obj to new objects and putting them into a map so you end up with a map that has 5 different objects. what is your question?

Comment: this might explain what you're seeing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/12429953#12429953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would expect that the following code:

```
HashMap<Integer, MyObject> hashmap ...    // Line 0
MyObject foo = new MyObject();            // Line 1
hashmap.put(1, foo);                      // Line 2
foo = new MyObject();                     // Line 3
hashmap.put(2, foo);                      // Line 4
```

will result in a hashmap where both values are the same.

---

Lets look at this example step by step:

1. After `Line 1`

   - the **stack** has 2 entries/pointers (hashmap, foo) and they are pointing to memory objects in
   - the **heap** (1 `HashMap` and 1 instance of `MyObject`).
2. After `Line 2`

   - the **stack** is unchanged.
   - the **heap** `HashMap` memory object now contains an entry that maps `1` to a pointer that points to the instance of `MyObject`
3. After `Line 3`

   - the **stack** pointer **foo** is now pointing to a different memory location on the heap (the newly created instance of `MyObject`)
   - the **heap** now holds a `HashMap` and **two** instances of `MyObject`
4. After `Line 4`

   - the **stack** is unchanged.
   - the **heap** `HashMap` memory object now contains 2 entries (`1` -> pointer to the first `MyObject` instance | `2` -> pointer to the second `MyObject` instance)

---

I hope you understand what i mean but important is: A variable/parameter is **NOT** the object itself. Its just a container that holds a pointer to the memory location.

Therefore if you give that pointer to the memory location to anyone else (in your case to a HashMap) then that other location won't know if the variable is changed later!

Comment: Ah, so the HashMap is accepting the memory location itself - NOT the variable to it. That would explain the behavior. So the parameter that enters the method is a variable containing a memory address. However, the HashMap actually stores the memory address value, NOT the reference to it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, thats it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same reference in all options, but you can't use the new keyword, so instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    obj = new AmazingObject();
    hashmap.put(i, obj);
}
```

Do:

```
obj = new AmazingObject();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hashmap.put(i, obj);
}
```

Comment: I get that! My question pertains to the `why` more so than the implementation. I should probably be more clear.

Comment: Well, think that, every new keyword a reference is created into memory, assignments only "points" to instances. (No pointer logics allowed)

Answer (score -1):

The input parameter is irrelevant since you keep reassigning it in your first for loop, so yes you end up with 5 new objects that are stored in the map.  This is one reason why I always make input parameters final - it prevents their reassignment which can cause confusion like this example

Comment: But isn't the same variable being overwritten again and again? I may be thinking of pointers a little too much here. So the value that gets passed into the HashMap is a reference copy? I keep imagining that variable pointing to the same memory location and that location being overwritten. That's where my confusion is coming from.

Comment: @Kris you need to understand that once you put the instance in the map it stays there even if the variable is reassigned to a different instance. In fact, you can even skip "obj = new AmazingObject();" and just write  hashmap.put(i, new AmazingObject();" and you'll get the same results.

Comment: I understand that much. Im just wondering what's happening here at a lower level. When you call 'new', you're getting a brand new memory location - which you then store in your variable. If I keep changing it, it will keep getting overwritten. My question is, why does the HashMap 'freeze' those address values?

Comment: Try to draw a sketch (heap, stack) for your example and you'll understand it pretty soon... Try to include where and what variables, pointers and memory-objects are in java!

Comment: Do they in any way differ from C++?